# DXGI: trying to get correct display mode from output (monitor)

Tags: direct3d, dxgi

I'm currently stuck with a pesky little issue. I developed an application that zeroes out the DXGI mode desc. structure and calls FindClosestMatchingMode() to, as advertised, "gravitate towards the desktop resolution".

This works fine if the laptop(s) run fully on their own display -- as soon as I plug in another monitor it goes berserk. In the case I extend my desktop it will still correctly get the laptop monitor resolution, yet the attached one (running 1080p) will yield a preference for 800*480 :) (sure, poor man's 16:10, but...)

Doing the same thing with the monitors cloned/combined (results in 1 output device), even if their resolution is equal, gives the same 800*480 crap.

What gives? And has anyone perhaps found a way to properly get a display's current mode through DXGI or a pointer for a wholly different yet functional approach to this here problem?

Life was easier back in the D3D9 days =)

-- Update

As it turns out any FindClosestMatchingMode() call made on the IDXGIOutput instance belonging to the external monitor behaves differently (and in most cases plain wrong) compared to the internal display, even though their native resolution is identical. To top it all off, other systems don't have this issue yet I can't get around supporting this particular laptop including it's drivers.

Time for a good old setup dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but as I was constrained to these exact machines I settled for getting the monitor's current resolution through GetSystemMetrics() (SM_CXSCREEN/SM_CYSCREEN), which admittedly only works for the primary monitor but there's other ways, and feeding this resolution to the ModeToMatch structure fed to FindClosestMatchingMode().

It then settles for the correct (desktop) resolution.

Better answers are very welcome of course ;)